# sql: "Query the total amount of each revenue and expenditure category"?

Tags: sql, database

table: **category_info**
field: *category_code, category_name, parent_category_code, ...*

table: **income_expend_info**
field: *user_id, category_code, ie_amount, ...*

Comment: please attach some queries.. and tag which DBMS you are using.. So that it will be helpful. Please visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

select sum(ie_amount) from income_expend_table group by category_code

Comment: I need to get  the total amount of each category. However, the toal amount of parent category is equal to the sum of the total amount of subcategories.